# Faster s3 bucket duplication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to find a better command line tool for duplicating buckets than [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd).  `s3cmd` can duplicate buckets without having to download and upload each file.  The command I normally run to duplicate buckets using s3cmd is:

```
s3cmd cp -r --acl-public s3://bucket1 s3://bucket2
```

This works, but it is very slow as it copies each file via the API one at a time. If `s3cmd` could run in parallel mode, I'd be very happy.

Are there other options available as a command line tools or code that people use to duplicate buckets that are faster than `s3cmd`?

Edit: Looks like [s3cmd-modification](https://github.com/pcorliss/s3cmd-modification) is exactly what I'm looking for.  Too bad it does not work.  Are there any other options?

Comment: Not sure why this question is repeatedly being closed, since it seems a number of developers have run into it. 
Anyway, I solved it in highly parallel fashion, here's the link: https://github.com/cobbzilla/s3s3mirror

thanks!

  - jonathan.

Answer (score 182):

AWS CLI seems to do the job perfectly, and has the bonus of being an officially supported tool.

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://backup-mybucket
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Supports concurrent transfers by default. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html#max-concurrent-requests

To quickly transfer a huge number of small files, run the script from an EC2 instance to decrease latency, and increase `max_concurrent_requests` to reduce the impact of latency. Eg:

```
aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 200
```

Comment: How fast is it? Does it support concurrent sync-ing?

Comment: It supports non-concurrent sync based on file modified time, size, etc. It was blazing fast when I tried it. I believe the objects are copied directly on S3 without downloading them to the local machine. It doesn't run in parallel by default but I'm sure you could have multiple sync commands running on separate subfolders at the same time. It's fast enough that you probably won't need it running in parallel anyway. I just duplicated 100GB of data in a few minutes.

Comment: Slow as hell if the number of files is high.

Comment: When transferring many small files latency becomes the key constraint so running this command from an EC2 instance is essential.

Comment: I used this to build a docker and works pretty well https://github.com/sunshineo/s3-bucket-copier

Comment: This command is also much faster when both buckets are in the same region.

Comment: Now it DOES support concurrent syncing :-) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html#max-concurrent-requests

Comment: Works, but it was quite slow, indeed. (About 300GB / Hour in my case)  Maybe because I didn't `change default.s3.max_concurrent_requests` to 200.
Anyway, I had less than 1.5TB, so I'm glad I tried it without optimizing, that way, I'll be able to compare next time.

Comment: `aws configure set default.s3.max_queue_size 5000` can also have an impact on the speed, and if you've got the processing power available, higher values for both of these settings can make it go even faster.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40270349/622140 for 700MB/s+ transfers (that's 2500GB/hr).

Comment: Have a look at this blog... this might help https://neelbhatt.com/2017/05/26/best-tools-for-s3-amazon-web-serviceaws/

Comment: Protip - if you have a lot of files to move, don't waste your time with free-tier EC2 boxes. I just spun up some GIANT EC2 boxes (96 processors!!) to do the `aws sync`, and the whole thing was massively faster. I'll kill the boxes in a few more minutes and I suspect I'll have paid less than $1 to get the job done in 10% of the time.

Answer (score 75):

If you don't mind using the AWS console, you can:

1. Select all of the files/folders in the first bucket
2. Click Actions > Copy
3. Create a new bucket and select it
4. Click Actions > Paste

It's still fairly slow, but you can leave it alone and let it do its thing.

Comment: Is this copying the contents of the source bucket to my machine as it copies to the destination? There's a lot of network activity and browser inspector is extremely slow so it's hard to analyse. 600K/s out on my machine. This would then be a lot faster initiating the transfer within the amazon network... Gonna try there instead.

Comment: @BradGoss that's a good question. I assumed it was using the Amazon network to copy the contents of the bucket and wasn't doing any transferring to your local machine, but if you find out differently, let me know.

Comment: I just used this method today. It does not pull the files down to your local machine – it does a direct copy and is much, much faster.

Comment: It still fetch the file list. If the list is too long (dozen of thousands of files in my case) then it's slow as heck. And timeout/hang is extremely likely

Comment: can you logout of the cancel and keep this transfer happen on a background thread? or will logging out cancel the transfer?

Comment: Unfortunately this process is tied to the browser. :( From [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/MakingaCopyofanObject.html): "After you initiate copy process you must keep the browser open while the copy is in-progress."

Comment: @haz0rd Please see my last comment on this. Hope it helps.

Comment: "this process is tied to the browser" ... gaaaah!, wish I read that one earlier :)  I'm not recommending you running this 10 minutes before you want to go home

Comment: I'm trying to do this on a bucket with 8 million files in it. Don't know how many months it's gonna take me to select all the checkboxes...

Comment: This is a very slow process and it is peculiar that it would require my browser to be on for the process to continue.  Glancing at the network utilization, I believe this method almost certainly is downloading the 30mb worth of files to my browser and then uploading it back to amazon.  I recommend using CLI from an shell sitting on amazon's network.

Answer (score 29):

I have tried cloning two buckets using the AWS web console, the `s3cmd` and the AWS CLI. Although these methods works most of the time, they are painfully slow.

Then I found `s3s3mirror` : a specialized tool for syncing two S3 buckets. It's multi-threaded and a lot faster than the other approaches I have tried. I quickly moved Giga-bytes of data from one AWS region to another.

Check it out at https://github.com/cobbzilla/s3s3mirror, or download a Docker container from https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/pmoust/s3s3mirror/

Comment: If you have a lot of files to transfer, this is by far the best tool for the job. Shame it's so far down the list of answers...

Comment: Note to some people: Requires Java 6/7 to compile.

Comment: I'm using this from a EC2 instance and it works unbelievably fast! I had to replace the <source-bucket> and <destination-bucket> with the actual bucket name (not the endpoint or something like in AWS CLI).

Comment: Amazing tool, highly recommended over others, for large number of files. Control over number of copy threads is brilliant.

Comment: Don't you think it is safer to use aws-cli and not third party applications to do the job? After all we need to provide credentials or access keys to use these tools.

Comment: Unfortunately, this tool currently doesn't support syncing between 2 different accounts.

Answer (score 12):

For adhoc solution use `aws cli` to sync between buckets:

`aws s3 sync` speed depends on:
- latency for an API call to S3 endpoint
- amount of API calls made in concurrent

To increase sync speed:
- run `aws s3 sync` from an AWS instance (c3.large on FreeBSD is OK ;-) )
- update ~/.aws/config with:
  -- `max_concurrent_requests = 128`
  -- `max_queue_size          = 8096`

with following config and instance type I was able to sync bucket (309GB, 72K files, us-east-1) within 474 seconds.

For more generic solution consider - AWS DataPipeLine or S3 cross-region replication.

Comment: Do you know if I could expect the same performance if I used S3 cp? Are you sure that when you used sync it actually transfered all 309GB? sync will only sync files that are not the same or present in the other bucket.

Comment: Also, what are your thoughts on this for a use case where I have 1k or less files, but they are larger in size (10gb)? Do you think I would see similar performance to you?

Comment: @frosty, in my case destination bucket was empty. per `awscli` doc - `aws sync` copy only new and updated files. 
probably you should expect high performance with `aws cp`
(copying is done internally, your client just issue an API call).
performance depends on these factors:
1. latency between src and dst regions (e.g. us-east-X to us-west-X)
2. latency between your client and AWS API endpoint (how fast you can issue an API call)
3. amount of concurrent requests (how many requests per second your client can issue).

In my case 309G was copied between buckets in same region (us-east-1)

Answer (score 3):

As this is about Google's first hit on this subject, adding extra information.

'Cyno' made a newer version of s3cmd-modification, which now supports parallel bucket-to-bucket syncing. Exactly what I was waiting for as well.

Pull request is at https://github.com/pcorliss/s3cmd-modification/pull/2, his version at https://github.com/pearltrees/s3cmd-modification

Comment: s3cmd-modification saved me days of copying.

Answer (score 3):

Extending [deadwards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172214/deadwards) answer, in 2021 copying objects from one bucket to another takes **not more than 2 minutes** in **AWS console** for **1.2 GB data**.

1. Create bucket, enter the **bucket name, choose region, copy settings from existing bucket**. Create bucket.
2. Once bucket created, go to the source bucket to which you want to copy the files from.
3. **Select all** (if needed or else you can choose desired files and folders), **Actions > Copy**.
4. In destination, you need to **browse the bucket** to which the files and folders to be copied.
5. Once click the copy button, all the files and folders are copied within a minute or two.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any other S3 command line tools but if nothing comes up here, it might be easiest to write your own.

Pick whatever language and Amazon SDK/Toolkit you prefer. Then you just need to list/retrieve the source bucket contents and copy each file (In parallel obviously)

Looking at the source for [s3cmd-modification](https://github.com/pcorliss/s3cmd-modification) (and I admit I know nothing about python), it looks like they have not parallelised the bucket-to-bucket code but perhaps you could use the standard upload/download parallel code as a starting point to do this.

Comment: Yeah.  I have been toying with this idea and writing it in ruby with evented manner with event machine or threaded with JRuby.  However, s3cmd is already pretty complete and I'd rather just use that.  I have been talking with the developer of s3cmd, and he has a couple solutions in the pipeline that will likely address performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

a simple `aws s3 cp s3://[original-bucket]  s3://[backup-bucket] --recursive` works well (assuming you have aws cli setup)

Answer (score 1):

if you have aws console access, use `AWS cloudshell` and

use below command

`aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://backup-mybucket`

no need to install `AWS CLI` or any tools.

Command taken from the best answer above. Cloudshell will make sure that your command runs smoothly even if you lose connection and faster too since its straight aws-to-aws. no local machine in between.