# Image not Downloading from AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I manually uploaded an image on the newly created [S3 Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) using my AWS Account. My [S3 Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) policy is as follows

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3BucketName/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I click on the [S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) link generated for that image for that [S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) bucket, I am unable to view or download the uploaded image. When I inspect element on the browser I am getting the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

My [S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) Region is `Oregon`. Also my image size is just `3KB`. Can somebody let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your bucket policy file is okay. So this should work.

Check:

- Did you save the policy file correctly (checked via web console)?
- Did not you overwrite permissions on file level?

Comment: I have saved the policy file correctly and what is meant by overwrite permissions on file level?

Comment: I mean permissions on the file you try to download (the image). See for example [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691286/amazon-s3-bucket-returning-403-forbidden)

Comment: @muller the issue still persists. When I Manually uploaded a 40 kb File, I am able to view and download the image. But when I try to upload a 3 kb file, I am unable to view or download the image. I checked the file permissions and everything is fine.

Comment: so the *only* difference is the file size? In the same bucket? Uploaded the same way?

Comment: @muller yes. The bucket is the same and it was uploaded manually in the same way.