# AWS S3 Bucket suddenly responding to POST request with 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a website containing my portfolio, which is hosted in an AWS S3 Bucket. it used to work fine, but suddenly the contact me section stopped working.

I have a javascript file, contact_me.js referring to a php file, contact_me.php. When I try to click "Send" to send a mail to my email adress, I get the error

"mail/contact_me.php:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

When I just navigate in my browser to the path, I download the file, so I do seem to have access to it.

I have also gotten this error, while trying to change permissions in AWS, but to no avail:

```
jquery.min.js:4
POST http://ReplacedWithDummySite/mail/contact_me.php 403 (Forbidden)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
submitSuccess @ contact_me.js:21
(anonymous) @ jqBootstrapValidation.js:76
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

The line where it goes wrong is this: "g.send(b.hasContent && b.data || null)"

I have not done anything for this to break: it used to work just fine. I have checked the bucket permissions, since the obvious thing would be that the permissions are not public. I have set everything to public, and have the following bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-website-dummyarn/*"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Your bucket policy allows *all* S3 actions to everyone. This is highly inadvisable. If you mean for it to provide public read access only, as the Sid suggests, then change the action to s3:GetObject.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed that now. Still haven't solved the issue though, I've tried altering the bucket policy settings etc, but nothing seems to work. I've read a comment here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691286/amazon-s3-bucket-returning-403-forbidden" by "Sthe", talking about system time. Could this be the issue? I have not found how to change system time, or if that even is relevant for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have a javascript file, contact_me.js referring to a php file, contact_me.php. When I try to click "Send" to send a mail to my email adress, I get the error*
>
> *...it used to work just fine.*

You may be under that impression, but is genuinely not possible for this setup to have *ever* worked on S3.

S3 doesn't support PHP, or any server-side language.  S3 has never supported server-side scripting.

> You can host a static website on Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3). On a static website, individual webpages include static content. They might also contain client-side scripts. By contrast, a dynamic website relies on server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP, JSP, or ASP.NET. Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

The fact that you can download the file only indicates that it is stored on S3.  A web server that actually supports PHP would not let you download the file -- it would execute the file, on the server, and return the output that was generated.

Comment: Interesting, I could have sworn that it uses to work. I guess I only tested it locally. Thanks