# Getting 403 (Forbidden) when trying to delete image from s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using this library [react-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3) to upload images on S3 and delete from S3. Upload image is working fine but when I am trying to delete the file from s3 but whenever I try to delete I am getting 403.
I am passing the following URL in delete function:

```
https://abc-profile-images.s3.amazonaws.com/1601273978.331.jpeg
```

But In catch block I received the following URL (why is it including url with and without region at the same time)

```
 https://abc-profile-images.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/https://abc-profile-images.s3.amazonaws.com/1601273978.331.jpeg
```

Following is the object received in catch:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://abc-profile-images.s3-ap-southeast-1.am…ages.s3.amazonaws.com/1601273978.331.jpeg", redirected: false, status: 403, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
type: "cors"
url: "https://abc-profile-images.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/https://abc-profile-images.s3.amazonaws.com/1601273978.331.jpeg"
__proto__: Response
```

Following is my code:

```
import { deleteFile } from "react-s3";
import config from './s3config';

const options = {

    accessKeyId: config.ID,
    secretAccessKey: config.key,
    region: config.region,
    bucketName: config.name
}

const removeImage = (uri) => {
    console.log('file : ', uri)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        deleteFile(uri, options)
            .then(result =>  resolve(result))
            .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
}
export {
    removeImage
};
```

```
import { removeImage } from '../../common/imageDelete'
function MethodList(props) {

  const removeMethod = (e, page) => {
        let image = e.target.dataset.image;
      
         removeImage(image)
             .then(res => console.log('s3 delete result : ', res))
             .catch(res => console.log('Image catch', res))
         }
    }
export default MethodList
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon S3 bucket returning 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691286/amazon-s3-bucket-returning-403-forbidden)

Comment: @Constantin No. The issue I'm getting is from react-s3 library. The url received is wrong.