# AWS S3 bucket access denied despite public access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here's my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the CORS rules:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

I've enabled public access.

[image]

I'm getting access denied. It was working on last Monday. Nothing has changed since then. I even tried the clock answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691286/amazon-s3-bucket-returning-403-forbidden).

Nothing works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was accessing a folder. Apparently this isn't possible. I had to specify the specific item in the folder to access it so I changed the key from `folder` to `folder/item`.