# how to copy data in recursive way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm trying to copy data from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket. In source s3 bucket I've data in recursive folders structure.

How can I copy data to destination s3 bucket in same way data is present in source recursive folder structure manner ?

any suggestions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 copy files and folders between two buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295587/aws-s3-copy-files-and-folders-between-two-buckets)

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve data copy between s3 buckets in recursive way.

1. Using AWS CLI's [sync](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command:

Eg:
`aws s3 sync s3://mybucket-src s3://mybucket-target --exclude *.tmp`

2. Using `CopyObject` API when you're working with AWS SDK. This can be done across given programming languages as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_CopyObject_section.html).