# Amazon S3 server side bucket transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to transfer buckets between Amazon s3 accounts. I see there is s3cmd for unix and CloudBerry Explorer for Windows. I have tested both, but im not sure if the transfer (both accounts in same region) are server side or client side? Can this be done server side?

[S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)

[Cloudberry explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/)

From this question: [Best way to move files between S3 buckets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664904/best-way-to-move-files-between-s3-buckets)

I am also checking this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingRuby.html, i like ruby :)

Edit: Also in the CloudBerry Explorer, i have checked the server side transfer option, and i am using sync option, BUT i am still not sure if this is entirely client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if these tools are using the `PUT - Copy` method the file duplication is done entirely on the server-side.

You can read-up on the details in the [API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html).

Comment: I see, it just takes a lot of time for several files, i think it has to check file by file. Thanks.