# Is s3 sync supported from sdk instead of cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666240/1251549) is answer about how move files from one s3 bucket to another using `sync` command from **command line (cli)**:

```
aws s3 sync s3://from_my_bucket s3://to_my_other_bucket
```

Can this be invoked from javascript sdk? With searching I did not find any `sync` named method. So is it supported in sdk?

Answer (score 1):

You can see how this [node package](https://github.com/issacg/s3sync) does it.

Basically, it makes use of several `S3` instance methods to sync two buckets.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to sync thousands of files, and decided to make use of [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) to do it. I update the pipeline definition to point to the correct source and destination folders from my Lambda function, and then invoke it.

It uses 2 S3DataNodes and a CopyActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I found this really helpful article on cloning S3 bucket using Node.JS package "aws-sdk": [Node Clone S3 Bucket by Rajesh Babu][1]

I am quoting his approach here:

> - Fetch the list of Keys from the bucket and the target Prefix. (check AWS-SDK Javascript APIs)
>
>   Separate the files and directories, because we clone the directories and download the files.
>
>   Clone all the directories first, and then move on to download the files.
>
>   Download the files through streams and log success and failure respectively.

[1]: https://blog.bitsrc.io/a-practical-guide-to-building-a-node-js-service-on-an-aws-s3-bucket-aff19105ba83