# AWS S3 - move folder with all files problem

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to move data for example;

`Source = "Uploads/Photos/"`  to `Destination="Uploads/mytest/"`

I am getting error like that but but when i give a specific file this works.

Basically, I want to move folder with all files.

My code is below;

```
        public async Task<MoveResponse> MoveObject(MoveRequest moveRequest)
        {
            MoveResponse moveResponse = new MoveResponse();

            CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
            {
                SourceBucket = moveRequest.BucketName,
                DestinationBucket = moveRequest.BucketName + "/" + moveRequest.Destination,
                SourceKey = moveRequest.Source,
                DestinationKey = moveRequest.Source,
            };

            var response1 = await client.CopyObjectAsync(copyObjectRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response1.HttpStatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                moveResponse.IsError = true;
                moveResponse.ErrorMessage = "Files could not moved to destination!";

                return moveResponse;
            }      

            return moveResponse;
        }
```

Comment: You cannot move a folder, you can only move individual files and you *need to* move all individual files.

Comment: Do you have any example related to topic? If you have could you share with me, please? @luk2302

Comment: You can move folder to S3. I have updated sample code right below. it may help you! @Mehmet

Comment: Your code would need to `ListObjects` to obtain a list of objects to 'move'. Then, loop through each object and use `CopyObject` to copy it to the new location, then `DeleteObject` to delete the object from the original location.

Comment: Thank you your answer is logical. I get it, but there has to be an easier way. @John Rotenstein

Comment: If you want "easier", then you could use the AWS CLI (which makes the listing/copying/deleting API calls for you). Here's an old example in .Net: [Best way to move files between S3 buckets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14812248/174777)

Answer (score 1):

I hope, you are using high level S3 API's.

Check out this sample code

```
private void uploadFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string directoryPath = textBoxBasePath.Text + listBoxFolder.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
        string bucketName = comboBoxBucketNames.Text;
        string FolderName = listBoxFolder.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
        try
        {
            TransferUtility directoryTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(AwsAccessKeyID, AwsSecretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1));

            TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                KeyPrefix = FolderName,
                StorageClass = S3StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess,
                ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256,
                Directory = directoryPath,                    
                SearchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories,
                SearchPattern = "*.*",                    
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.AuthenticatedRead
            };
            ListMultipartUploadsRequest req1 = new ListMultipartUploadsRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName
            };

            var t = Task.Factory.FromAsync(directoryTransferUtility.BeginUploadDirectory, directoryTransferUtility.EndUploadDirectory, request, null);
            t.Wait();

            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The Directory '{0}' is successfully uploaded", FolderName));
        }
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        { }
    }
```

Comment: This code seems to be for **uploading** files to S3? The question is asking about **moving** objects within S3.

Comment: Oh! then he should use CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest to achieve moving object one folder to another.

Comment: Yes this is for the uploading. I need to only move from resource path to destination. @SantoshKokatnur