# Scala Copy large file between S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-s3

I need to copy S3 objects from one bucket to another using Scala every day. I am new to scala, is there an existing command/method to do this easily?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666240/7497127 maybe this answer could help

Comment: @JAMSHAID I need to do this using Scala.

Comment: You can send http requests using Scala. The API might not be available but the http requests always work