# How to migrate millions of files in aws s3 bucket from one account to another really fast

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket in account A with millions of files that take up many GBs

I want to migrate all this data into a new bucket in account B

So far, I've given account B permissions to run s3 commands on the bucket in account A.

I am able to get some results with the 
`aws s3 sync` command with the setting `aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 100`

its fast but it only does a speed of some 20,000 parts per minute.

Is there an approach to sync/move data across aws buckets in different accounts REALLY fast?

I tried to do aws transfer acceleration but it seems that that is good for uploading and downloading from the buckets and I think it works within an aws account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faster s3 bucket duplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663016/faster-s3-bucket-duplication)

Answer (score 3):

> 20,000 parts per minute.

That's > 300/sec, so, um... that's pretty fast.  It's also 1.2 million per hour, which is also pretty respectable.

[S3 Request Rate and Performance Considerations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html) implies that 300 `PUT` req/sec is something of a default performance threshold.

At some point, make too many requests too quickly and you'll overwhelm your index partition and you'll start encountering `503 Slow Down` errors -- though hopefully aws-cli will handle that gracefully.

The idea, though, seems to be that that S3 will scale up to accommodate the offered workload, so if you leave this process running, you *may* find that it actually does get faster with time.

Or...

> If you expect a rapid increase in the request rate for a bucket to more than 300 PUT/LIST/DELETE requests per second or more than 800 GET requests per second, we recommend that you open a support case to prepare for the workload and avoid any temporary limits on your request rate.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

Note, also, that it says "temporary limits."  This is where I come to the conclusion that, all on its own, S3 will -- at some point -- provision more index capacity (presumably this means a partition split) to accommodate the increased workload.

You might also find that you get away a much higher aggregate trx/sec if you run multiple separate jobs, each handling a different object prefix (e.g. asset/1, asset/2, asset/3, etc. depending on how the keys are designed in your bucket, because you're not creating such a hot spot in the object index.

---

The copy operation going on here is an internal S3-to-S3 copy.   It isn't download + upload.  Transfer acceleration is only used for actual downloads.